# grails Objects query when hasMany relationship is NULL

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-domain-class

Not able to get the list of Objects when a hasMany attribute is null.

```
Class User {
...
List<EMail> emails
static hasMany = [emails: EMail,... ]
static mappedBy = [emails: 'customer',...]
... 
}
```

Where Email is another Class with some String Attributes

Now i am trying to make a simple query as:

Method 1:

```
def users = User.findAllByEmailsIsEmpty()
```

This is giving Error as:

```
 Queries of type IsEmpty are not supported by this implementation
```

Method 2:

```
def users = User.findAllByEmailsIsNull()
```

This is giving all the users even those have Email object associated with it.

Then I thought of trying Criteria Query (https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html )

Method 3:

```
def userCriteria = User.createCriteria()
    def users = userCriteria.list(){
        sizeEq('emails', 0)
    }
```

This gives No result ( users.size() is 0 )

Method 4:

```
def userCriteria = User.createCriteria()
    def users = userCriteria.list(){
        isNull('emails')
    }
```

This again gives all the Users even those who don't have emails.

Method 5:

```
 def userCriteria = User.createCriteria()
    def users = userCriteria.list(){
        isEmpty('emails')
    }
```

This gives the Error :
    Queries of type IsEmpty are not supported by this implementation

Method 6:

```
def userCriteria = User.createCriteria()
    def users = userCriteria.list(){
        eq('emails', null)
    }
```

This again lists down all the users.

```
PS: Grails is configured with Database as MongoDB.
```

Comment: Try `def users = User.where {
       emails.size() == 0
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the grep method. Something like this:

```
nullEmailUsers = User.list().grep {
    !it.emails
}
```

Comment: thnx, but this is what i am avoiding iterating over each user, as this is not a scalable solution.

Comment: right; it's an if-all-else fails method. I would keep searching because I feel it is doable.

Comment: trust me, i have that code already before you posted, but i am feeling so wrong in using it.

Comment: buddy, I just tried this: `User.withCriteria { isEmpty('emails') }`. It works!

Comment: I am getting Queries of type IsEmpty are not supported by this implementation

Comment: grails 2.4.3 , Mongo 2.6.4

Comment: grails 2.5.0, H2; regardless of the DBMS, isn't Hibernate doing the work here, which is 4.3.8.1 in my case?

Comment: I am not using any hibernate plugin. should i use one for mongo ? ( gmongo is enough right ?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78607/discussion-between-mohsenmadi-and-rats).

Answer (score 0):

User.findAll { emails.id != null } do the job!